# The fastest way of making splitted bars in html - css - jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, split, bar-chart

Currently i am using ul li for the making following bars

[image]

But they are extremely slow on google chrome. So i have to use another method other than 
ul li

How can i make it ? they are dynamic and changing according to the monsters stat powers

thank you.

Comment: extremely slow. i dont know what causes but when i decrease the bar count it get a lot faster

Comment: you can login and try yourself   http://www.monstermmorpg.com/SelectWhichMonster.aspx   username : test password : test     try with google chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than deal with transparency as Jake suggested, you could simply nest two divs with a different background for the above div.

[Attached JS Fiddle for your convenience](http://jsfiddle.net/hwPaY/5/)

Comment: this is not a solution. i need a splitted bar

Comment: Simple, make the background a 1x10px bar. With the following format [000000000x] Where 0 is a completely transparent pixel and x is a black picel. When this repeats it will create bars.

Comment: [No Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/hwPaY/8/), but if I see MonsterMMoRPG.com using the png on my site I will flip out. So make your own png ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could make each bar a solid color div with a transparency.  Then just overlay the div on top of your background grid, adjusting the width as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding Jake Feasel's suggestion:

```
Make each FULL BAR a single graph and only show background-position 
partial as needed.
As a matter of fact, you should be very familiar with sprites and, 
in this case, there is no better use for them.
```